# Angular JS ng-grid is not populating data when used with route provider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am trying to display data using ng-Grid. The problem is with the route provider, When I am using a separate view to display data it is not being displayed, however if I do the exact same code without the route provider,and load just that page, it works perfectly fine. Below is my code

**Index.html**:

```
            <div ng-view></div>
            <!-- JQuery ================================================================ -->
            <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

            <!-- AngularJS ============================================================= -->
            -->
            <script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="/lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js"></script>

            <!-- AngularJS App Code ==================================================== -->
            <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/app.js"></script>
            <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/controllers.js"></script>
```

**List.html:**

```
    <div  class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

app.js:

```
        angular.module('ngdemo', ['ngdemo.controllers','ngGrid']).
            config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'list.html', controller: 'UserListCtrl'});
                $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
            }]);

//Controller to bind data to the ng-Grid
```

controller.js

```
        var app = angular.module('ngdemo.controllers', ['ngGrid']);

        app.controller('UserListCtrl',function ($scope) {

         $scope.myData = [{"color": "red","value": "#f00"}];         
         $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' }; 
});
```

The error it display is as follow:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
    at new C (xxx/js/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js:1:12069)
    at xxx/js/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js:1:25099
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.forEach (xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:130:11)
    at w.buildColumns (xxx/js/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js:1:25064)
    at g.filteredRowsChanged (xxx/js/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js:2:5200)
    at i.evalFilter (xxx/js/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js:2:9164)
    at Object.n (xxx/js/ng-grid-2.0.7.min.js:2:17009)
    at Object.applyFunction [as fn] (<anonymous>:778:50)
    at Object.Scope.$digest (xxx/lib/angular/angular.js:7942:27)
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have tried upgrading all to latest versions but still problem persists. If you have a solution please post it. Thankx

Answer (score -1):

yes the problem is you are using a route provider to display your data and you are trying to include multiple views onto the same page at once; which cannot be done.

**Solution**

If you want to include multiple views on the same page, you need to use **"ui-router"** instead of **"ng-route"**. Then you can include multiple views on the same page.

Here are some common reasons ui-router is chosen over ng-route.
ui-router allows for [nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views) and [multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). This is very useful with larger apps where you may have pages that inherit from other sections.

Comment: -1 : I don't think it is true as he is not trying to include many views. He has only one definition of a ng-view and this code is very common way to use routeProvider.